# Java Regex Pattern

Tags: java, regex

So I ran into this bit of regular expression pattern code:

```
.*?(callback|cron)$
```

I think `.*?` means any character occurring zero or multiple times but not sure about the rest :3

Comment: [You could read up on regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: Check out this [webpage on regex explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=.*%3F%28callback%7Ccron%29%24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(callback|cron)$
```

`$` means `Matches end of line`

So it means if the string has a word ending in `callback` or `cron` then it would be true.

**sample:**

```
    String s = "lawlasd callback";
    System.out.println(s.matches(".*?(callback|cron)$"));
```

**result:**

```
true
```

Now if the string is only `lawlasd` it would return `false` because it does not end with the word `callback` or `cron`.

Comment: use `\b` for word match that was missing. It should be `\b(callback|cron)$`

Answer (score 1):

To continue from @Rod_Algonquin's answer: You can see an example here that will explain every component in more detail

http://regex101.com/r/bM0sO9/1

> .*? matches any character (except newline) Quantifier: Between zero
>   and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
>   [lazy]
>
> 1st Capturing group (callback|cron) 
>   1st Alternative: callback
>      callback matches the characters callback literally (case sensitive)
>
> 2nd Alternative: cron 
>      cron matches the characters cron literally (case sensitive)
>
> $ assert position at end of the string

It would match a line with callback or cron as the last string on the line. It would also match 'dodecahemidodecacron' as long as it was at the end of the string.